# How to enable AWS RDS SQL Server loging/logout logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using AWS RDS SQL Server，We have to enable RDS SQL Server login/logout logs, is it possible to enable and export RDS SQL Server user login and logout events to CloudWatch?